# Jquery invalid argument IE7-IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a link which deletes a product from cart, works in all browsers except IE7-IE9.

I get this error in IE console log:

```
SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
jquery.min.js, line 4 character 7871
```

Script: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

It works kind of like an accordion, when deleted it "slides up" and it seems this jquery effect is causing it. The Product is not deleted either, when this error occurs. Im clueless now, anyone have any idea?

**EDIT:**

```
if ( document.documentElement.currentStyle ) {
currentStyle = function( elem, name ) {
    var left, rsLeft, uncomputed,
        ret = elem.currentStyle && elem.currentStyle[ name ],
        style = elem.style;

    // Avoid setting ret to empty string here
    // so we don't default to auto
    if ( ret === null && style && (uncomputed = style[ name ]) ) {
        ret = uncomputed;
    }

    // From the awesome hack by Dean Edwards
    // http://erik.eae.net/archives/2007/07/27/18.54.15/#comment-102291

    // If we're not dealing with a regular pixel number
    // but a number that has a weird ending, we need to convert it to pixels
    if ( !rnumpx.test( ret ) && rnum.test( ret ) ) {

        // Remember the original values
        left = style.left;
        rsLeft = elem.runtimeStyle && elem.runtimeStyle.left;

        // Put in the new values to get a computed value out
        if ( rsLeft ) {
            elem.runtimeStyle.left = elem.currentStyle.left;
        }
        style.left = name === "fontSize" ? "1em" : ( ret || 0 );
        ret = style.pixelLeft + "px";

        // Revert the changed values
        style.left = left;
        if ( rsLeft ) {
            elem.runtimeStyle.left = rsLeft;
        }
    }

    return ret === "" ? "auto" : ret;
};
    }
```

The error occurs on:

```
style.left = name === "fontSize" ? "1em" : ( ret || 0 );
```

Comment: Did you trace the stack? That's probably not where the issue originated. You'd have to find the relevant line of code that triggered the error.

Comment: Could you show the function you are using to delete the product

Comment: What do you mean by trace the stack?
updated my post what i think it is.

Comment: it would help if you used the non-minified version of jQuery, so you could get real variable names.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @Barmar 1.7.1, in the link.

Comment: updated my post, with non-minified jquery.

Comment: The problem is not jQuery, it must be somewhere in your code. Trace the stack with IE dev tools to find the culprit. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699336(v=vs.85).aspx#callstack